# Reached graphical.target, but still have to type startx to start gui

Tags: boot, manjaro, startx

I use **Manjaro Linux** and after an update, when I boot, `journalctl` says the system reached graphical target, but it starts up in `tty1` and I need to type `startx` to start the **KDE**. Then I type my password again in a `kdewallet` popup, to connect to wifi.

After that, everything works fine.  In **Manjaro**, the gui starts in `tty1`, while in other distros, it usually starts in `tty7`.

I tried setting the default to `graphical.target` with the `systemctl` command, and by editing grub menu by replacing the quit parameter by `systemd.unit=graphical.target`, but it still starts up in the `tty1` session.

I also tried adding a custom entry in the grub menu, but that does not help either.

To add this to the grub menu:

- copy the first grub menu entry from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` into the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`
- replace the quit command by `systemd.unit=graphical.target`
- change the `menuentry` title and run `sudo update-grub`

Any ideas on how to get the system to start normal again.
I posed the question in the **Manjaro** forum a week ago, but there is no reply.

I suppose it will be faster to just re-install, but I am curious why this happens, and how to correct it.

---

Thanks for the tips.
I found that `ssdm` is installed but not active, it is masked.

When I try to re-install it, I get this error:

```
    sudo pacman -S sddm

    warning: sddm-0.19.0-2.2 is up to date -- reinstalling
    ...
    error: sddm: signature from "Philip Müller (Called Little)<philm@manjaro.org>" is invalid
    :: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/sddm-0.19.0-2.2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
    Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] 
    error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
    Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
    [marc@ass ~]$ systemctl enable sddm.service
    Failed to enable unit: Unit file /usr/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service is masked.
```

When I look for `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service`, I see that it is empty.

Am I correct that there is some kind of packaging error, and that due to the corrupted package, the system blocked it from starting ?
If the package is corrupt, should not more people have this problem ?

Should I wait some time for the package to get repaired, or should I uninstall it and install another greeter like `lightdm` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `/etc/systemd/system/default.target` pointing to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target` must contain:

`Wants=display-manager.service`

To check your default systemd target:

```bsh
systemctl get-default
graphical.target

# ls -l /etc/systemd/system/default.target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 40 Jan 1  2020 /etc/systemd/system/default.target -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target
```

2. `/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service` symlink pointing to an actual Display Manager unit must exist, in my case it's `/usr/lib/systemd/system/lxdm.service`.

To check it:

```bsh
ls -l /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 36 Jan 1  2020 /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/lxdm.service

# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/lxdm.service
[Unit]
Description=LXDM (Lightweight X11 Display Manager)
#Documentation=man:lxdm(8)
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service
After=systemd-user-sessions.service getty@tty1.service plymouth-quit.service livesys-late.service
#Conflicts=plymouth-quit.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lxdm
Restart=always
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
#BusName=org.freedesktop.lxdm

[Install]
Alias=display-manager.service
```

If these two requirements are met, you must have a graphical display manager on boot.

Most likely you'd want to have SDDM installed as it's a preferred DM for KDE. [Here's how you can install/reenable it](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Install_Display_Managers#SDDM).

Answer (score 1):

Setting `graphical.target` does not automatically put you in a graphical session. What it does is to ensure that when you boot your system, all programs/services that are expected to be running in the `graphical.target` target are run.

When you enable a service, you are are adding that service to some target (`multi-user`, `graphical`, etc). In what particular target depends on the configuration of that unit.

You need to enable some program so that when the system enters the `graphical` target it will take care of starting a graphical session.

Normally, this program is a Display Manager. Make sure you have some installed on you system. If you are using KDE, you might prefer using `sddm`. In my Arch system I would install it by running:

```bsh
sudo pacman -S sddm
```

Then you need to enable that unit. To do so run

```bsh
systemctl enable sddm.service
```